# AWS Amplify Datastore Query Dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore

So i wanted to give AWS Amplify a try, as the new project I am starting will start our simple but will grow to be more complex and I dont want to go the Firebase route for that reason. So I setup Auth and created my Data Models and added the Amplify Lib to my angular front end. I can login and read my data. So far so good.

Now I wanted to do a basic query on my data. Filtering based on a basic string field is easy for things like the Name:

`const members = await DataStore.query(Member, m => m.firstName("eq", "Steve"));`

What I can't seem to find is any documentation on how you would query things like dates?

I have a model called Event, and there is how you'd do a typical create for an event (note the fields `StartTimestamp`, and `EndTimestamp`):

```
await DataStore.save(
    new Event({
        "Title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "StartTimestamp": "1970-01-01T12:30:23.999ZM",
        "EndTimestamp": "1970-01-01T12:30:23.999ZM",
        "Notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    })
);
```

Both `StartTimestamp`, and `EndTimestamp`are of type `AWSDateTime`:
[image]

When pulling the data for events I see the type in JS as I read them is string. So how do I query the dates then? string comparison wont help. I know the underlying DB for AWS Amplify is GraphQL and querying a date there is easy but I am still limited to what the Amplify DataStore Lib gives me to work with.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add some additional information about AWS and date fields.

- AWStimestamp is a an integer value representing the number of seconds before or after 1970-01-01-T00:00Z
- AWSDateTime is a string field that represents the timestamp as an ISO 8601 formatted string.

More info in [AWS types reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html)

Both have their uses.

- AWStimestamp takes up less space in the database.
- AWSDateTime is easy to process when debugging as it is human readable
- both sort correctly lexicographically
- both support query predicates using 'gt', 'lt', 'eq', AWStimestamp will use a number comparison and AWSDateTime will use a string comparison

As stated above, just convert your variable date value to a ISO 8601 formatted string representation.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Amplify leverages AWS AppSync to manage the underlying GraphQL. A model can indeed be setup in the AWS Admin UI with a field of type AWSDateTime. In the local amplify installation folder the model schema shows the field as string. AppSync indeed confirms that AWSDateTime is an [extended ISO 8601 date and time string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html).

The [AWS Amplify Datastore documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js#predicates) only make mentions of predicates to filter queries for strings, numbers and lists not dates. This means you cannot query against actual date values as below (in Angular)

```
const members = await DataStore.query(Member, m => m.StartTimeStamp("lt", new Date()));
```

However you can leverage the idea that ISO 8601 date strings are implicitly [lexicographically ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922398/what-is-the-appropriate-date-formatting-so-the-lexicographic-ordering-is-the-sam) to compare the dates. You can then query by first changing the date you wish to compare to into a string in the appropriate ISO 8601 format then doing a string comparison. The previous search then becomes (in Angular)

```
const currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
const members = await DataStore.query(Member, m => m.StartTimeStamp("lt", currentDate));
```

By converting the date to compare with to a string you can therefore use the string predicates to filter against AWSDateTime fields in queries.