# How to store current Date & Time in regular format in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store current Date and time in firebase Database, But it is in millsec format.I want to save this in regular format  i.e dd-mm-yy hr-ms.I am using SErverValue.Timestamp.

```
String id=databaseuser.push().getKey();
            User user=new User(id,getname,getgenre,ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            databaseuser.child(id).setValue(user);
            Toast.makeText(this, "User Added!..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[image: This shows in millsec format]

Comment: Its better to store the time as you are doing now. When retrieving you can format it into dd-mm-yy or any format you want by using https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754625/6763544

Comment: Is there not any way to store like this

Comment: It's a standard way of dealing with timestamps.Any specific reasons to store it as a string?

Comment: Ok...By seeing the data in firebase one can know the date and time very easily.So i am trying to do this

Comment: If you have "time" as the key & developers accessing the Firebase to "see" the data, it is evident that it's a timestamp. So it's better to implement standard practices.

Comment: does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard practice to store the time as the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. When retrieving you can format it into dd-mm-yy or any format you want by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754625/6763544). You can use the same process to store it in the format you want. However, it isn't recommended.